# Setting multiple inputs to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input, state

I have an calendar app that reads events in the following format

```
{
  title: "Werk",
  start: moment().toDate(),
  end: moment(),

  allDay: false,
},
```

And I have inputs so that the user can make their own events.

```
<form>
  <div className="text-center col-sm-12">
    <input placeholder="start date" required></input>
    <input placeholder="end date" required></input>
    <input placeholder="Title" onChange={this.myChangeHandler} required></input>{" "}
    <br /> <button className="text-center">Add event</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My problem is, I have set state to be user input before, but not in this format. The state needs to be an object that has 4 properties. `title, Start, End, and allday`
and each of these need to come from from the inputs

Overall I am a bit stumped on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

 My full code is [here](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/AimhighChallege)
I hope I was clear enough, please ask if I was not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use `useState` of React.

```js
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
  title: "Werk",
  start: moment().toDate(),
  end: moment(),
  allDay: false,
});
```

And then set values and handlers for every `input` like below:

```html
<input placeholder="start date"
  value={state.start}
  onChange={e => setState({...state, start: e.target.value})}
  required></input>
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use state value for every input's value.

Hope this could be helpful.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';

import './App.css';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    events: [
      {
        title: 'Werk',
        start: moment().toDate(),
        end: moment(),
        allDay: false
      }
    ],
    title: '',
    start: '',
    end: ''
  };

  myChangeHandler = (key) => (event) => {
    this.setState({ [key]: event.target.value });
  };

  onAddEvent = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { title, start, end, events } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      events: [
        ...events,
        {
          title,
          start: moment(new Date(start)),
          end: moment(new Date(end)),
          allDay: false
        }
      ]
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.onAddEvent}>
          <div className="text-center col-sm-12">
            <input
              placeholder="start date"
              required
              onChange={this.myChangeHandler('start')}
            ></input>
            <input
              placeholder="end date"
              required
              onChange={this.myChangeHandler('end')}
            ></input>
            <input
              placeholder="Title"
              onChange={this.myChangeHandler('title')}
              required
            ></input>{' '}
            <br />{' '}
            <button type="submit" className="text-center">
              Add event
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <Calendar
          localizer={localizer}
          defaultDate={new Date()}
          defaultView="month"
          events={this.state.events}
          style={{ height: '100vh' }}
        />
        <div className="list">
          <ul>
            <li>Display Weekly view X</li>
            <li>Highlight today X</li>
            <li>Allow navigation to different weeks X</li>
            <li>allow adding new events</li>
            <li>allow editing existing events</li>
            <li>allow deleting events</li>
            <li>Persisting data </li>
            <li>Use apis to load and save data </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This was originally how I thought of doing it, but with this method the user wouldn't be able to add multiple events

Comment: you should be able to add multiple events. did you try this on your side? Or try this and let me know if it is what you need - https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-field-v8vby?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It looks like this is on the right track, but I added a ```console.log()``` statement to the onchange event and it is telling me that the ```event``` state is undefined

Comment: what do you mean by `event` state? there isn't any state value named `event`, but `events`

Comment: You're right that was a mistake on my end. I think the issue is the calendar needs to read the events as an object with those properties, not properties alone in the state. Is this possible?

Comment: please check the code carefully. Current state has `events` array which is used for calendar events. Also, current state has `title`, `start`, `end` string values which are used for tracking input changes. So when you change the input values, `title`, `start`, and `end` state is chaned. When you click `Add event`, a new event object with these information will be added to `events` state array, which will reflect Calendar to show added event.